# Can a SQLite table have more unique fields other than the primary key?

Tags: sqlite, unique-constraint

I don't want a composite primary key. All I want is that another field must be also unique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you just need to mark the column as unique.

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Look under SQL Data Constraints.